# Web server is displaying files requested without extensions (bypassing rewrite rules)

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the following `.htaccess` being used for a front controller:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This works fine for the majority of cases, however, when I visit the location of an actual file without its extension, it is outputting the contents of that file in the browser.

For example, let's say I have the following files in the same directory as index.php:

- composer.lock
- config.php

When I visit `myscript.com/config` it is not point to `index.php?path=config`, it is pointing to the `config.php` file. Same with the composer file. If I visit `myscript.com/composer` (without even including `.lock` in the URL) it is output the contents of `composer.lock` in the browser.

It is very bizarre, how do I stop this?

Comment: What's your web server?

Comment: [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/)

Comment: Could be apache's multiviews.

Comment: Dead right. Adding `Options -MultiViews` fixed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Options -MultiViews` fixed this issue.